# Prolog - Filter list with only even numbers

Tags: list, prolog

I have que next Prolog function that only multiply any number (F) you enter with every element in the list[], for example input: multiplyf(2, [5,4,8], N). output: [10,8,16]. This function works properly (you can try it) but now i need to filter only the even numbers to multyply F keeping the odd numbers the same, example before: input: multiplyf(2, [5,4,8], N). output: [5,8,16], Any idea how i could filter this list? I try with many ways but i didn't get the answer.

```
multiplyf(_,[],[]):-!.
multiplyf(F,[X|Xs], [Y|Ys]):-
Y is F*X,
multiplyf(F, Xs, Ys), !.
```

I try with:

```
even(X) :- 
Y is mod(X,2),
Y =:= 0.
```

But when i inserted even(X) in the first function it doesn't work too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

While we're code golfing, how about this:

```
multiplyf(_F, [], []).
multiplyf(F, [X | Xs], [Y | Ys]) :-
    Y is X + ((1 - (X mod 2)) * X * (F - 1)),
    multiplyf(F, Xs, Ys).
```

Depending on whether `X mod 2` is 0 or 1, `Y` is computed as `X + X * (F - 1)`, i.e., `X * F`, or as `X + 0 * Something`, i.e., X.

There you go:

```
?- multiplyf(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Ys).
Ys = [1, 6, 3, 12, 5] ;
false.
```

This leaves a choice point on my old version of SWI-Prolog. Are newer versions more willing to index on a non-first argument?

Comment: The best answer!

Comment: Scryer indexes on the first nonvar argument.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is OK in spirit but in the details it is a mess. Maybe @Nicholas Carey was just [trying to provoke me](https://xkcd.com/386/) ;-)

You can test for odd and even using a bitmask on the least significant bit of an integer.

```
odd(X) :- X /\ 0x1 =:= 1.
even(X) :- X /\ 0x1 =:= 0.
```

There are other ways to achieve the same but this is the one with least typing. Read the docs on is/2 to understand the pitfalls of writing `0 is something something`.

If you want to avoid cuts altogether you can use the following well-understood and documented approach that takes advantage of clause indexing on the first argument.

```
mf(Factor, Xs, Ys) :-
    mf_1(Xs, Factor, Ys).

mf_1([], _, []).
mf_1([X|Xs], F, Ys) :-
    LSB is X /\ 0x1,
    mf_2(LSB, X, Xs, F, Ys).

mf_2(0 /* even */, X, Xs, F, [Y|Ys]) :-
    Y is 2 * X,
    mf_1(Xs, F, Ys).
mf_2(1 /* odd */, X, Xs, F, [X|Ys]) :-
    mf_1(Xs, F, Ys).
```

This doesn't have cuts or `->`, doesn't leave choice points, and doesn't work with floats.

Comment: Not sure why you say your obscure odd/even tests are "the one with least typing". `X mod 2 =:= 1` is not only clearer but also one character less!

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie haha well obscure to you maybe you haven't been damaged for life by having programmed in C

Answer (score -2):

To modify your `multiply/3`:

```
multiplyf( _ , []    , []     ) :- ! .
multiplyf( F ,[X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
  Y is F * X,
  multiplyf(F,Xs,Ys), !.
```

is straightforward enough:

```
multiply_evens( _ , []     , []     ) .
multiply_evens( X , [Y|Ys] , [Z|Zs] ) :- even(Y), Z is X * Y , multiply(X,Ys,Zs) .
multiply_evens( X , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- odd(Y), multiply_evens(X,Ys,Zs) .

even(X) :- 0 is X mod 2 .

odd(X)  :- 1 is X mod 2 .
```

This is also arguably the most declarative solution. Very little is left to doubt about intent.

You can condense it by using a cut (`!`) to eliminate a choice point (after all, the number in question isn't going to cease to be positive/negative):

```
multiply_evens( _ , []     , []     ) .
multiply_evens( X , [Y|Ys] , [Z|Zs] ) :- even(Y), !, Z is X * Y , multiply(X,Ys,Zs) .
multiply_evens( X , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- multiply_evens(X,Ys,Zs) .

even(X) :- 0 is X mod 2 .
```

You can condense it even further by using a *soft cut*:

```
multiply_evens( _ , []     , []     ) .
multiply_evens( X , [Y|Ys] , [Z|Zs] ) :-
 ( even(Y) -> Z is X * Y ; Z is X ),
 multiply(X,Ys,Zs) .

even(X) :- 0 is X mod 2 .
```

And there's something to be said for extracting the multiplication bit from the list traversal itself:

```
multiply_evens( _ , []     , []     ) .
multiply_evens( X , [Y|Ys] , [Z|Zs] ) :- multiply_even(X,Y,Z), multiply_evens(X,Ys,Zs) .

multiple_even(X,Y,Z) :- even(Y), !, Z is X * Y .
multiply_even(_,Y,Y) .

even(X) :- 0 is X mod 2 .
```

Comment: `->` is not a soft cut.

Comment: Gave you a minus because it is a very bad habit to use `is/2` with a ground term on the left side. One way to test for odd/even that also enforces integers is: `N /\ 0x1 =:= 0` for even and `N /\ 0x1 =:= 1` for odd.

Comment: See my answer for a worked out solution to the problem that uses idiomatic Prolog. I say "idiomatic" because to me the intent is clear enough.

Comment: @TA_intern: didn't know `it is a very bad habit to use is/2 with a ground term on the left side`. Where have you found it ?

Comment: In the version using ```->```, the goal ```Z is X``` should be ```Z = Y```, and the goal ```multiply(X,Ys,Zs)``` should be ```multiply_evens(X,Ys,Zs)```.

Comment: @CapelliC is/2 works by first evaluating the right side, _then_ attempting to unify it with the left side. This makes it fail for comparisons like `1 is sin(pi/2)`; on the other hand, `sin(pi/2) =:= 1` succeeds.

Comment: @TA_intern: true, but `1.0 is sin(pi/2)` succeeds. Not that I like it... but seems it's more a problem about implicit conversions performed by `(=:=)/2`, not sure right now, but maybe I'll try to ask about this behaviour on the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/)

Comment: @CapelliC I suspect it has been discussed. I should maybe re-read the docs in SWI-Prolog to make sure that it isn't already documented.